# Comparing Current Time to Timestamp

Tags: r

I am trying to develop an R script that compares a timestamp to the current system time. If the timestamp is within the past 5 minutes compared to the system time, continue the script, if not stop the script entirely.

Could someone help me write up a template for how this might look with an if else function.

I have a version that runs based on date, but not based on timestamp, see below:

```r
New_data <- LoadingTable %>% filter(load_date == today()) %>% select(unique_id)

if((wday(today(), label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE) %in% c("Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri") & nrow(New_data) == 0 )) { QUIT SCRIPT FUNCTION and alert me}
```

Example data:

```
> dput(head(example_data))
structure(list(ID = 1:3, status = c("ACTIVE", "CANCELLED", "HOLD"
), time_status = structure(c(1707768357, 1707768357, 1707768357
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: example: `as.POSIXct(1707771389, origin = '1970-01-01')`

Comment: You want to know if something is within the last 5 minutes but you use `today()` that returns a `Date`. What do your "timestamps" look like?

Comment: Welcome to SO, stk19209413! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages); sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: @r2evans - that is a different function that is similar to what I'm trying to do. The example is focused on if the most recent loaded data was from the same day, whereas I want to, in the new function, find out if the most recent loaded data was within the last 5 minutes.

the timestamps are YYYY-MM-DD Hr:Min:Sec (ex: 2024-02-09 02:34:57)

Comment: Okay, I think what you want/need will be clearer once you add some sample data.

Comment: Sure thing! Apologies if this isn't formatted effectively!

Loaded data:

format: ID | STATUS | LOAD_TIMESTAMP
example: 1234 | ACTIVE | 2024-02-09 02:34:57

What I want to do is compare the LOAD_TIMESTAMP to the current time (whenever the script is ran) and tell me if the LOAD_TIMESTAMP is within the past 5 minutes. If it is not, run a stop script which I have already built and can put behind the if function IF...{STOP SCRIPT function}

Let me know if that is clearer..thanks!

Comment: Can you run `dput(head(LoadingTable))` and paste the output into the body of your question, which you are encouraged to edit?

Comment: "formatted correctly", I had suggested `dput(head(x))` and now JonSpring has too. It's a really good/effective way to share an unambiguous and easily-used piece of data.

Comment: Sorry, all - first time asking a question on SO - I've updated the question with a dput(head(x)) with some sample data. The goal would be to compare the current system time with the time_status